# What is the meaning of rank in the context of change-detection?

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, change-point

In a technique that uses CUSUM for change-point detection in this [paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mahimkar/MERCURY_sigcomm10.pdf), the first step is given below:

> Let $x_1, x_2,..., x_n$ be the $n$
>   samples in an event-series. The
>   samples are ranked in increasing order
>   and the rank $r_i$ for each sample is
>   calculated. In case of ties, we assign
>   average rank to each sample. The
>   cumulative sums are computed as: $S_i = S_{i-1} + (r_i - \bar{r})$.
>   If the ranks are randomly distributed, then
>   there is no change-point. However, if
>   there is indeed a change-point in the
>   event-series, then higher ranks should
>   dominate in either the earlier or
>   later part of the event-series.

I am not quite sure I understand the meaning of rank in this context. For instance, if n=10 and my data points are: 5, 2, 4, 1, 9, 2, 9, 2, 10, 1 can someone please clarify what is really being done here?

- Sort in increasing order: 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 9, 9, 10
- Assign Average Ranks to break ties: What does this step mean?
- Assign Final Ranks: What does this step mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your data:

```
cp <- c(5, 2, 4, 1, 9, 2, 9, 2, 10, 1)
```

then the ranks, with ties being given average of the ranks, are:

```
> rank(cp)
 [1]  7.0  4.0  6.0  1.5  8.5  4.0  8.5  4.0 10.0  1.5
```

What is being done here? If you sort the data in increasing order, then we have a `1` in both rank order positions 1 *and* 2. We could assign rank 1 to both `1`s, or rank 2, or as stated above, the average of the rank orders (1/2) / 2 = 1.5. This is why the two `1`s have been given rank of 1.5 in the above output from R.

Now look at the next values in the rank order, the `2`s. The `2`'s are in rank order positions 3, 4, and 5, therefore they all get rank 4 from (3+4+5) / 3 = 4, as this is the average of the tied ranks for these values.

If we initiate $S_0 = 0$, i.e. the zeroth cumulative sum is 0, we compute the $i$th cumulative sum ($S_i$) as the previous cumulative sum ($S_{i-1}$) plus the difference between the rank of the $i$th data point ($r_i$) and the average over all ranks $\bar{r}$.

For the above data, the average rank is:

```
> rcp <- rank(cp)
> mean(rcp)
[1] 5.5
```

The values $r_i - \bar{r}$ for this set of data are:

```
> rcp - mean(rcp)
 [1]  1.5 -1.5  0.5 -4.0  3.0 -1.5  3.0 -1.5  4.5 -4.0
```

and the cumulative sums are:

```
> cumsum(rcp - mean(rcp))
 [1]  1.5  0.0  0.5 -3.5 -0.5 -2.0  1.0 -0.5  4.0  0.0
```

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: I was curious if the technique is a standard or they did something more. This clears it up. Thank you for your time and explanation. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: I hope you won't mind if I ask a related question. Why is ranking important? Is there some effect is it addressing here?

Comment: @Legend in the paper you link to, the authors state "Since the test is based on ranks, it is robust to outliers and requires no special distributional assumptions." So there are two reasons. I'm not really that familiar with the CUSUM literature though; my experience is with these tests for structural changes in regression models, so the CUSUM is on residuals and there the actual residuals are used, not ranks, but in other respects the CUSUMs are calculated in the manner described.

Comment: @Legend, @Gavin, the basic idea behind the CUSUM tests is that under null hypothesis  you sum up zero mean independent identically distributed random variables. This sum converges to random walk. If there is a change point, then the convergence does not happen. So ranking is important here, since under null hypothesis ranks are independent. Note that the actual convergence should be proved, since for funky samples you can get that there is no convergence even in case of no change point. Time trends come into mind.

Comment: @mpiktas but residuals are assumed independent random variables so ranks are not a requirement - the `strucchange` package doesn't use ranked residuals IIRC.

Comment: @Gavin, strictly speaking residuals are not independent, but that does not matter. Note that in the article original data is ranked not residuals. I think this may be a crucial assumption. The approach described would not work on residuals.

Comment: @mpitkas I think we are talking at crossed purposes. I thought you are commenting on the comments here? CUSUM can be applied to model residuals - see the `strucchange` package - and I only mentioned that this was my experience with CUSUM tests. Note I said _assumed_  - from a linear regression say we might CUSUM on the assumed IID ~N(0, $\sigma$) residuals.